# How to find the file corresponding to a pipe opened by a process?

Tags: linux, files, process, pipe

I created this script, which listens for characters received on a hardcoded pipe, and tries to `eval` those characters. I call my script `loop_executor.sh`
This is all it contains:

```
!/bin/bash

while :
do
    x=`cat /tmp/console_test`;
    echo "received $x"
    eval $x
done;
```

I execute my script with a double click.

I want to see what files this process has open:

```
> $ pgrep loop_executor.sh
1234

> $ ll /proc/1234/fd
dr-x------ 2 userX domain^users  0 Oct 20 17:57 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 9 userX domain^users  0 Oct 20 17:57 ../
lr-x------ 1 userX domain^users 64 Oct 20 17:57 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 userX domain^users 64 Oct 20 17:57 1 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 userX domain^users 64 Oct 20 17:57 2 -> /home/local/groupX/userX/.xsession-errors
lr-x------ 1 userX domain^users 64 Oct 20 17:58 255 -> /home/local/groupX/userX/Desktop/loop_executor.sh*
lr-x------ 1 userX domain^users 64 Oct 20 17:57 3 -> pipe:[225812]
```

FD 3 points to a "pipe". Well i know what file it uses, because I'm the one that hardcoded the file in the script, but I'd like to get this information (if possible) from another source (since my script is just a POC, and it could be a process whose code is not open to me).

What I understood, is that `pipe:[225812]` doesn't point to the inode of my file.

```
ll -i /tmp/console_test 
16519395 prw-r--r-- 1 userX domain^users 0 Oct 20 18:14 /tmp/console_test|
```

So my question is: If processess can open pipes, which are files on my system, can I determine which files those pipes "corresponded" to?

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 if that matters.

**[EDIT]**
Found the `cat` process that was reading from my pipe. It has the same opened pipe as its parent process, so it doesn't make much of a difference here -> i still don't know just by looking at `pipe:[225812]` what file -if any - that is.

Comment: Are you sure you used those backtick quotes on the pgrep line?!

Comment: Why not `. /tmp/console` instead?

Comment: you wont find `pipe:[225812]` - it's an anonymous pipe. likely you can reference it w/ the special link `/dev/fd/3`

Answer (score 2):

Your script does not have `/tmp/console_test` opened, the `cat` process does. Your script is reading from a pipe that is connected to the `cat` process; that's what you're seeing in your question.

Search for the `cat` process and check that one out.

You probably want something like this:

```
while read x; do
    echo "received $x"
    eval "$x"
done < /tmp/console_test
```

Note the added quotes around the parameter to `eval`